# Download Zip using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to download zip from spring boot rest api but getting error.

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: .
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
```

Download file location.

[image]

Code for downloading.

```
@PostMapping("/downlode")
    public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> generator(@RequestBody Input input)
            throws IOException, JSONException, InterruptedException {
        
        FileSystemResource fileResource = new FileSystemResource("./");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        String filename = "myarchive.zip";
        headers.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.attachment().filename(filename).build());
        headers.setContentLength(((FileSystemResource) fileResource).contentLength());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(fileResource);
    }
```

Comment: "AccessDenied" sounds pretty understandable. You aren't allowed to access whatever it is you are trying to access. Sounds like less of a programming error and more of a problem with the permissions of the filesystem

Comment: You need to include the *full* stack trace in your question.

Comment: I guess You run spring boot as a jar. then your code `FileSystemResource("./")` will access your jar file. not the working directory (I guess).  check your jar is include the zip file ?

Comment: no i am running it as spring boot app